# How do I store a value from an Element in Capybara/Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

How do I store the '23 results' in a variable?

```
<span dir="auto">23 results</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code  :

```
element = browser.find_element(:css,"span[dir='auto']").text
```

if you print `element` you should get  `23 results`

Comment: I suspect whether he is asking the selenium answer since he has added capybara tag.

Comment: @Rajagopalan : - Selenium is also tagged my old friend

Comment: People those who ask questions related to WATIR, Capybara always add selenium tag since those are wrapper around ruby selenium binding. Infact I really don't know what answer he wants. So your answer might be a correct one as well.

Comment: Sure thing! Thanks.